# Problems with memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

I am working on an algorithm that tries to solve a mathematical problem using CPLEX and I am getting some wrong answers because of some mistake with some pointer. As a result I tried to use valgrind to track the issues and fix the problems, unfortunately I managed to track down the memory leaks but without being able to find out how to fix them.
So I will provide you all the parts of the code that are connected with the problem and ofcourse the valgrind error as well hoping that sb will be abel to help.  In order to give you a brief idea of what is going on this algorithm is actually a subproblem of e bigger problem and the subproblem is minimum flow cost problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) and the procedure is that after receiving some information from the main bit of the problem the subproblem is initialized constracting the set of nodes, arcs, the bounds and the costs and all other proper information, and then the solver class is used to solve the problem. 
Hopefully the following bids of codes plus the comments will help you understand what's going on:

1) The problem initialization function (no input or output):
    {

```
    /*parameters used for the initialazation,fUCProblemInstance is a class connected   with the main problem which is used to pass informations to the sub problem */
    const Index horizonLen = fUCProblemInstance->GetHorizonLen();
    const Index numNodes = horizonLen + 1;
    const Index numArcs = horizonLen * 3;
           /*MCFCplex() is the class of the solver and fMCFClass is a pointer to the class MCFClass which is a general class containing general information (virtual functions, indexes, etc) for all the possible solvers of the subproblems, except from MCFCplex there are 3 more possible solvers with different classes, */
            fMCFClass = new MCFCplex(); 

    /* basic initialization of values for the nodes (starting,ending), the bounds, the deficits and the size of the problem*/
    fDualSolution.fHydroDuals.Resize(numNodes, numNodes);
    tFlows upperBounds(numArcs, F_INF);
    tFlows deficits(numNodes, 0);
    tNodes startingNodes(numArcs, InINF);
    tNodes endingNodes(numArcs, InINF);

    Index i;

    // Seting arcs
    fFirstA2 = numNodes-1;
    fLastA2 = 2*(numNodes-1);
    fFirstA3 = 2*(numNodes-1);
    fLastA3 = 3*(numNodes-1);

    for (i=0; i<numNodes-1; ++i)
    {
        assert (startingNodes[i]==InINF);
        assert (endingNodes[i]==InINF);
        assert (startingNodes[i + fFirstA2]==InINF);
        assert (endingNodes[i + fFirstA2]==InINF);
        assert (startingNodes[i + fFirstA3]==InINF);
        assert (endingNodes[i + fFirstA3]==InINF);

        startingNodes[i] = i; // A_1 arcs
        endingNodes[i] = i+1;

        startingNodes[i + fFirstA2] = i; // A_2 arcs
        endingNodes[i + fFirstA2] = numNodes-1;

        startingNodes[i + fFirstA3] = i; // A_3 arcs
        endingNodes[i + fFirstA3] = numNodes-1;
    }


    // Seting deficits
    deficits[0] = -(fHydroUnit->GetInitialFlood() + fHydroUnit->GetInflow()[0]);
    deficits[horizonLen] += -deficits[0];
    for (i=1; i<horizonLen; ++i)
    {
        deficits[i] = -fHydroUnit->GetInflow()[i];
        deficits[horizonLen] += -deficits[i];
    }
    // Adjust lower bound scaling
    deficits[0] += fHydroUnit->GetMinFlood();
    deficits[horizonLen] -= fHydroUnit->GetMinFlood();

    // Setting upperbounds (and lowerbounds)
    for (i=0; i<horizonLen; ++i)
    {
        upperBounds[i] = fHydroUnit->GetMaxFlood() - fHydroUnit->GetMinFlood();
        upperBounds[i + horizonLen] = fHydroUnit->GetMaxUsage();
        upperBounds[i + 2*horizonLen] = fHydroUnit->GetMaxSpillage();
    }

    /*After the initialization of all the parts the solver is also initialized in function LoadNet*/
    fMCFClass->LoadNet(numNodes, numArcs, numNodes, numArcs,
        &upperBounds[0], NULL, &deficits[0],
        &startingNodes[0], &endingNodes[0]);
}
```

2) The initialization function of the solver:

```
void MCFCplex::LoadNet( cIndex nmx , cIndex mmx , cIndex pn , cIndex pm ,
        cFRow pU , cCRow pC , cFRow pDfct , cIndex_Set pSn ,
        cIndex_Set pEn )
{
// allocating and deallocating memory- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

if( ( mmax && nmax ) && ( ( nmx != nmax ) || ( mmx != mmax ) ) ) {
MemDeAlloc();
nmax = mmax = 0;
}

if( ( mmx && nmx ) && ( ( nmx != nmax ) || ( mmx != mmax ) ) ) {
nmax = nmx;
mmax = mmx;
MemAlloc();
}

if( ( ! nmax ) || ( ! mmax ) )  // just sit down in the corner and wait
 return;

// now setting up data - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

n = pn;
m = pm;

// setup data structures for arc creation/deletion- - - - - - - - - - - - -

 VectAssign( ArcPos , FNumber( 0 ) , FreePos = m );
 VectAssign( ArcPos + m , FNumber( Inf<FNumber>() ), mmax - m );
 #endif

  // create and set up temporary data structures - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

  int* stn = new int[ m ];
  int* enn = new int[ m ];

 for( Index i = m ; i-- ; ) {
 stn[ i ] = pSn[ i ] MINUSONE;
 enn[ i ] = pEn[ i ] MINUSONE;
 }


 double* sup = new double[ n ];

 if( pDfct )
 VectMAssign( sup , pDfct , n );  // invert the sign of deficits
 else
 VectAssign( sup , double( 0 ) , n );

 double* upc = new double[ m ];

 if( pU )
  for( Index i = m ; i-- ; )
  if( pU[ i ] == Inf<FNumber>() )
   upc[ i ] = CPX_INFBOUND;
  else
   upc[ i ] = double( pU[ i ] );
  else
  VectAssign( upc , CPX_INFBOUND , m );

  double* obj = new double[ m ];

 if( pC )
 for( Index i = m ; i-- ; )
 if( pC[ i ] == Inf<CNumber>() ) {
  #if( DYNMC_MCF_CPX )
  ArcPos[ i ] = pU[ i ];
 #endif
 obj[ i ] = upc[ i ] = 0;
  }
 else
  obj[ i ] = double( pC[ i ] );
 else
 VectAssign( obj , double( 0 ) , m );


 // load internal structure of Cplex- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

 status = CPXNETcopynet( env , net , CPX_MIN , n , sup , NULL , m , stn ,
         enn , NULL , upc , obj , NULL );

 assert( ! status );

 // setup QP data - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

 qp = NULL;             // problem is initially Network
 QPMthd = qpNSimplex;   // set default QP solving method to Network Simplex


 // delete temporaries- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

 delete[] obj;
 delete[] upc;
 delete[] sup;
 delete[] enn;
 delete[] stn;
 status = MCFClass::kUnSolved;

  }  // end( MCFCplex::LoadNet )
```

The functions used inside loadnet:

```
 template<class T1, class T2>
 static inline void VectMAssign( T1 *g1 , const T2 *g2 , MCFCplex::Index n )
 {
 // g1 := - g2

 for( ; n-- ; )
 *(g1++) = - *(g2++);
  }

  template<class T>
  static inline void VectAssign( T *const g , const T x , MCFCplex::cIndex n )
  {
  // g[ i ] = x for each i = 0 .. n - 1

  for( T *tg = g + n ; tg > g ; )
  *(--tg) = x;
   }

   void MCFCplex::MemAlloc( void )
   {
    // create a new Cplex problem- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    int ts;
    net = CPXNETcreateprob( env , &ts , "NET" );

    // create data structures for arc creation/deletion- - - - - - - - - - - - -

    ArcPos = new FNumber[ mmax ];

   // if necessary, resize static members - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

   if( mmax > nmaxarc ) {
   if( nmaxarc ) {
   delete[] ChangeUB;
   delete[] val;
   delete[] ind;
   }

  ind = new int[ nmaxarc = mmax ];
  val = new double[ nmaxarc ]; 
  ChangeUB = new char[ nmaxarc ];

  VectAssign( ChangeUB , 'U' , nmaxarc );
   }
 }  // end( MemAlloc )

 /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

 void MCFCplex::MemDeAlloc( void )
  {
   delete[] ArcPos;
   if( net ) 
      CPXNETfreeprob( env , &net ); 
   else {
    CPXfreeprob( env , &qp );
    delete[] Startn;
    delete[] Endn;
         }
   }  // end( MemDeAlloc )
```

Then the problem is being solved using function:

```
   void MCFCplex::SolveMCF( void )
   {

    if( net ) {
            CPXNETprimopt( env , net );  // call the network simplex- - - - - - - - - - 
            status = CPXNETgetstat( env , net );
              }

         else {
            CPXqpopt( env , qp );       // call the QP solver - - - - - - - - - - - - -
            status = CPXgetstat( env , qp );
              }

   switch( status ) {
   case( CPX_OPTIMAL ):       status = MCFClass::kOK;
                          break;
   case( CPX_INForUNBD ):
   case( CPX_INFEASIBLE ):    status = MCFClass::kUnfeasible;
                             break;
   case( CPX_UNBOUNDED ):     status = MCFClass::kUnbounded;
                             break;
   default:                   status = MCFClass::kStopped;
   }

    }  // end( MCFCplex::SolveMCF )
```

And the error I am getting in Valgrind:

```
  Invalid read of Size 8 [PID 963]:
  by OX5522AA: CPXNETprimopt
  by 0X4b17C0: MCFCplex::SolveMCF (MCFCPLEX.cpp:442)
  .
  .
  . The path continues until it reaches the main function from where function is originally called
```

So I tracked the origins of the problem which are printing that:

```
  Adress 0x66ed440 is 16 bytes after a block of size 192 free'd [PID: 2024]
  at 0x4C2AF50: operator delete[](void*)(vg_replace_malloc.c:537)
  by 0x4302FA: MCFCplex::Loadnet(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, double const*, double const*, double const*, unsigned int const*, unsigned int const*)(MCFCPLEX.cpp:442)
  .
  .
  . The path continues until it reaches the main function from where function is originally called
```

As I am using valgrind tool inside eclipse I even get a pointer to where 16 bytes after a block of size 192 free'd and it shows me the line in function loadnet where the array obj is deleted:

```
 delete[] obj;
```

So more or less this is my problem and any help is really appriciated and needed, in case more clarification is needed please let me know.

Comment: Take-home lesson: use proper containers, e.g. `std::vector`, rather than raw pointers.

Comment: if you need resizing of the objects you delete the arrays and allocate them again. But if not you still allocate them again. You have too many `delete[]` all over the place, this was bad practice since the 80s, try to do you allocations and deallocations in ONE place. Even better, use `std::vector`